# Simple img carousel function not working?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, carousel

So I'm creating a simple image carousel for a mock webpage I'm building. 
I'm currently following [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sDsyHJnkZn0) on YouTube. Minute: 7:10 shows the function I'm asking about.

In this tutorial he creates this jquery function to activate the carousel.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $(".nextLink").on("click", function(){
        var currentActiveImage = $(".image-shown");
        var nextActiveImage = currentActiveImage.next();

        currentActiveImage.removeClass(".image-shown").addClass(".image-hidden");
        nextActiveImage.addClass(".image-shown").removeClass("image-hidden");
    });

});
```

Here's the HTML

```
<div class="carousel-outer">
            <figure class="carousel-inner">
                <img class="image-shown" src="images/team/alex_morrales.jpg" alt="">
                <img class="image-hidden" src="images/team/david_kim.jpg" alt="">
                <img class="image-hidden" src="images/team/jenny_tabers.jpg" alt="">
                <img class="image-hidden" src="images/team/joey_barrett.jpg" alt="">
                <img class="image-hidden" src="images/team/melinda_lee.jpg" alt="">
                <img class="image-hidden" src="images/team/rachel_dotson.jpg" alt="">
            </figure>
            <div class="img-buttons-box">
                <div class="img-buttons">
                    <a class="previousLink" href="#">Previous</a>
                    <a class="nextLink" href="#">Next</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Here's the CSS

```
.image-shown {
    display: inline-block;
}

.image-hidden {
    display: none;
}
```

I'm under the impression that the above function in itself is enough to have the carousel work well and cycle through the photos seamlessly.

Always displaying the next one in the lineup and hiding the rest.

However, this is obviously not the case as this is what it looks like before and after I hit the "next" button for the first time (it doesn't do anything on subsequent presses).

Before

[image]

After

[image: the page after clicking "next"]

Help understanding why the function, as is, isn't seemingly enough to make the carousel work is greatly appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

When you reference a class in `.removeClass()` or `.addClass()` you dont have to write the dot before the class.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $(".nextLink").on("click", function(){
        var currentActiveImage = $(".image-shown");
        var nextActiveImage = currentActiveImage.next();

        currentActiveImage.removeClass("image-shown").addClass("image-hidden");
        nextActiveImage.addClass("image-shown").removeClass("image-hidden");
    });

});
```

PS: I saw this by using the devtools; clicked on "Next" and saw how an `img` got classes with the dot. Just an advice if you want to debug DOM changes quickly.